# Counting the occurences of letters in a table with awk

Tags: awk

I have a file similar to this one:

```
location1 person1 -
location2 person1 a
location3 person1 c
location2 person2 x
location1 person2 -
location3 person2 -
```

Each file has multiple entries for each person at different locations (notice the order of locations is not the same for each person). The third column is either a letter or '-'.

I have awk reading the file, and I want to produce a result table like so:

```
person location1 location2 location3
person1 0 1 1
person2 0 1 0
```

Where there was a letter for the person and location, it is recorded as a 1 in the table, and if the original table had a '-', then it is recorded as a 0 in the result table.

My humble attempt (it isn't working well, but at least I think an associative array should be in the code somewhere):

```
awk -F" " '{if($3!="-") a[$2]=$1} END {for (k in a) print k} file.txt
```

Comment: You will always have `location` 1-3 (or) 1-N ?

Comment: 1-N, and it might be good to account for cases where people don't appear in all the locations. For example person3 might only have two rows, for location1 and location2..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the data in a wannabe-matrix and then loop through the also stored locations and persons!

```
{
seen[$1 FS $2]=(($3 == "-") ? "-"  0 : 1);
locs[$1]
people[$2]
}
END {
      for (loc in locs) 
        printf "\t%s", loc
      print ""
      for (person in people) {
          printf "%s%s", per, FS
          for (loc in locs) 
              printf "%d\t", seen[loc FS person]
          print ""
       }
}
```

See it in action:

```
$ awk -f a.wk your_file
location1   location2   location3
person1 0   1   1   
person2 0   1   0
```